# Linkname Alias problem

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, url, data-views, tracking

I have an issue that I cannot resolve.

We create our emails based on our own templates (template based email). For a number of our emails, a URL is constructed dynamically via Ampscript. The problem now is that the LinkName in the _click data view is not filled. It turns out that this is because emails created based on a template contain impression regions (somewhere in the backend) and therefore the LinkName is not filled. However, we do need this because we use the same URL in different places of the email. Is there a workaround so that the LinkName is filled in the _click dataview?

Comment: Well - it depends on what you need in the LinkName field. I will recommend creating dynamic link alias, by placing ampscript in the _alias="..."_ within the _a href_. As you probably already select your impression region based on some logic, I would recommend passing a string deifing the link alias on to the impression region.

Comment: I learned that dynamic aliases are not recommended. And I don't use impression regions myself. Apparently MC adds this automatically when you create an email based on an email template (instead of an email based on HTML)

Comment: Impression regions are added automatically if you are using [Dynamic Content blocks](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_dynamic_content.htm&type=5) in your email. It has nothing to do with templates (as these are purely a placeholder for your blocks)